# Get label (static) text from another application

Tags: .net, vb.net, stringbuilder

I've researched both on the web and on here, but I haven't seen anybody that has the same problem as me.

I use the *AutoIt Window Info* tool to get another applications label (static) id. The *AutoIt Window Info* tool gives me the ID of that control (label). So I can get that text using the following code:

```
For Each pr As Process In Process.GetProcessesByName("AnotherAppExeName")

    Dim sb as New StringBuilder
    sb.Capacity = 500
    GetDlgItemText(pr.MainWindowHandle, 1044, sb, sb.Capacity)

    '1044 Is the ID of another application's label
    'I print the string:

    MessageBox.Show(sb.ToString)
Next
```

This works. I can get the text of the control (id:1044) from another application. But the other application has a lot of labels and I can only get the one with 1044 ID. For example, there is another label with 1043 ID, but when I apply the same things, it returns an empty string.

What can I do to solve this?

A screen from AutoIt Window Info Tool:

[image: AutoIt]

Comment: The odds that MainWindowHandle is the proper handle are quite small.  Controls that have an ID are usually inside a dialog window, a dialog is never the Main window.  You'll need to write code to enumerate windows, like EnumThreadWindows or FindWindowEx.  Type "ui automation library" in a google query, first hit is a good one.

Comment: Yes. I guess you are right. I used WinSpy++ now and i figured out that the control which i want to take is under a parent! My problem is there are few parents and all of their control IDs are 0. I used the handle i took from WinSpy++ and it worked. But how I will find the handle of  the parent I want?